# Почему в php “lcfirst()” не работает для русских символов?

Tags: php

lcfirst() не работает для русских символов.

Как преобразовать первый символ строки на кириллице в нижний регистр?

Например, чтобы строки "Купить телевизор Samsung" или "Купить телевизор Рубин" преобразовались в "купить телевизор Samsung" или "купить телевизор Рубин" соотвественно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Как преобразовать первый символ строки на кириллице в нижний регистр?*

Вот пара альтернативных вариантов:

```
$str = 'Какой-То Текст';
echo mb_lcfirst($str) . "\n"; // какой-То Текст

function mb_lcfirst($str) {
    return mb_strtolower(mb_substr($str, 0, 1)) . mb_substr($str, 1);
}


$str = 'кАКОЙ-тО тЕКСТ';
echo mb_ucfirst($str); // КАКОЙ-тО тЕКСТ

function mb_ucfirst($str) {
    return mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($str, 0, 1)) . mb_substr($str, 1);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю! А для чего в первом варианте конкотинация ' . "\n" ' ?

Comment: @auditor8880 `"\n"` - это символ перевода строки. Можете его просто удалить.

Comment: Не помешает добавить к коду: `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');` Иначе будут символы вопросительного знака.

Answer (score 1):

На основе комментариев в [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ucfirst.php#57298):

```
//Стандартный lcfirst не работает для кириллицы
function custom_lcfirst($str, $e='utf-8') {
    $fc = mb_strtolower(mb_substr($str, 0, 1, $e), $e);
    return $fc.mb_substr($str, 1, mb_strlen($str, $e), $e);
}
```